# It's possible or Not : paypal personal account to get Api-(username,password and Signature) in Magento2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal, paypal-express

I have paypal personal account I need to configure paypal express checkout.

I don't have Paypal Business account So -

I need to know any trial possibility for Configure paypal express checkout in Magento2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. You need Paypal Business account for getting username, password, signature, setup IP etc.

The personal account is for purchase only.

Comment: Ok Sir thank you.